# My bash script to track disk space usage over time: any advice on how to make it less hacky (e.g. avoiding 'eval')?

Tags: bash

The following script sits at the end of my ~/.bash_profile. I want it to run once a day when I open an interactive login shell (unless I chose to skip), to keep track of larger changes in disk space usage, with the output of (g)du stored inside a file named after the current date.

Leaving aside, if you allow, the wisdom of what the script itself does, do you have any advice how to rewrite it to make it less hacky?

For example, I'm using 'eval', which I understand is frowned upon. Then again, simply replacing

```
eval $gdu_log_command
```

by

```
($gdu_log_command)
```

doesn't work.

Or: putting the entire thing into an alias is pretty ugly I guess, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Any suggestions what I could change, while preserving what it does?

```
gdu_log_today=$(date +"%y-%m-%d")$(echo ".txt")

gdu_log_command="sudo gdu / -hPx --si --threshold=1G > ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today"

alias gdu_log='if [[ ! -e ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today ]]
                 then read -p "Run disk space log now? (y)es, (s)kip, no: " gdu_log_user_input
                   if [[ "$gdu_log_user_input" = "y" ]]
                     then
                       echo "$gdu_log_command"
                       read -p "Execute? (y)es, cancel: " gdu_log_user_input_2
                         if [[ "$gdu_log_user_input_2" = "y" ]]
                           then eval  $gdu_log_command
                         fi
                   elif [[ "$gdu_log_user_input" = "s" ]]
                     then 
                       echo "Skipping today."
                       touch ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today
                   else
                     echo "Will ask again later."
                   fi
               fi'

gdu_log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use functions:

```
gdu_log_today=$(date +"%y-%m-%d")$(echo ".txt")

gdu_log_command() {
    sudo gdu / -hPx --si --threshold=1G > ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today
}

gdu_log() {
    if [[ -e ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today ]] && return

    read -p "Run disk space log now? (y)es, (s)kip, no: " gdu_log_user_input

    if [[ "$gdu_log_user_input" = "y" ]]; then
        declare -f gdu_log_command  # Edited command

      # Also consider this alternative, which uses `sed` to remove the
      # first line (i.e., the function header)
      # declare -f gdu_log_command | sed '1,2d;$d'

        read -p "Execute? (y)es, cancel: " gdu_log_user_input_2
        if [[ "$gdu_log_user_input_2" = "y" ]]; then 
            gdu_log_command
        fi
    elif [[ "$gdu_log_user_input" = "s" ]]; then 
        echo "Skipping today."
        touch ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today
    else
        echo "Will ask again later."
    fi
}

gdu_log
```

**EDIT** Just to neaten the code slightly.

Also, instead of adding it to your `~/.bash_profile`, why not use a [`crontab`](http://crontab.org/)? If you saved your above script to a file located at `~/gdu_log.sh`, you could do:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add this line:

```
# The 5 characters represent:
#    minute hour day-of-month week-of-year day-of-week
# So, <MM> <HH> * * * represents every day at HH:MM
# e.g., everyday at 3:30am   => 30 3 * * *
#       everyday at 9:15pm   => 15 21 * * *
#       everyday at midnight => 0 0 * * *
0 3 * * * root /bin/sh /home/root/script.sh
```

That'll run the script daily at 03:00am.

**EDIT** per comments, see the script above (edited line has a comment next to it). `declare -f` prints the entire function and code to the console. E.g.,

```
# This first line is me pasting the function declaration into
# my console, so I can run `declare -f` against it
nick@nick-lt:~$ gdu_log_command() { sudo gdu / -hPx --si --threshold=1G > ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today; }
# The `declare -f` command and its output to the console:
nick@nick-lt:~$ declare -f gdu_log_command
gdu_log_command () 
{ 
    sudo gdu / -hPx --si --threshold=1G > ~/Downloads/gdu-logs/$gdu_log_today
}
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't know there are functions in bash. One minor quibble: in my original script, before calling the critical line, I first show it, once by echoing the variable, then evaluating it. That's the part that breaks when trying to do it with ($_) instead. Any idea how to fit this into your functional rewrite? Simply defining a string variable inside the gdu_log_command() function with the command doesn't seem to work, i.e. I still need to use eval, not ($_).

Comment: Yes, the actual command that I haphazardly execute with sudo, blindly basically :D

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, right now,
    gdu_log_command is potentially executed twice now, no? Once after the outer conditional, then another time if the inner conditional is 'yes' again.

Comment: @BertZangle Ahh I'll change that to the above comment. One moment.

Comment: @NickBull - that's just wrong. `echo "$(gdu_log_command)"` is exactly the same as `gdu_log_command`. Did you even try `echo "$(ls)"` to see what you were advising?

Comment: @BertZangle Of course it does, otherwise it can't get the output from the command. How else will we `echo` it? **EDIT** Sorry, wait do you want to echo the contents of the function, i.e., the code?

Comment: @NickBull - for the purpose of just showing the exact command instead of the funtion definition, maybe it is better to remove the function name and braces by `declare -f gdu_log_command | sed '1,2d;$d'`

Comment: @NickBull Haha, sorry, should have said it more clearly: since I'm using sudo "blindly" in a way, on a command variable, to ease my mind I at least want to have the command bound to a single variable, then once indeed *echo* the code, followed by *evaluating* the code. I'll look at the update...

Comment: @alvits Nice suggestion! We'll let the OP decide, please take note of that comment Bert and try replacing the `declare -f` line with Alvits' instead, see which you prefer. I've added it into the post too :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, NickBull and @alvits. Will mark as answered immediately.